# Extract and count value from standard .gz log files on an hourly basis

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, zcat

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of a particular string from a bunch of `.gz` logfiles on an hourly basis. Each logfile statement starts with the following time format:

```
2013-11-21;09:07:23.433.
```

For example, to be more clear, find the count of occurrences of string `"abc"` between 8am to 9am, then 9am to 10am and so on. Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you just want to count occurrences, you may simply `zcat` the contents of the file, `grep` the portion that describes what you're looking for -- words/time intervals --, and finally sort/count (`sort | uniq -c`) the entries. The following would probably suffice:

```
zcat *.gz | grep <word> | grep -oP "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2};\d{2}" | sort | uniq -c
```

The above command shall find the lines in your logfile that contains the `<word>` you're looking for, extract both date and hour from such entries, and later count the occurrences.
In case you don't want to take into account days/months/years, you may use:

```
zcat *.gz | grep <word> | grep -oP "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2};\K\d{2}" | sort | uniq -c
```

The `\K` added in the `grep` expression is a flag for look-behind in PCRE -- Perl Compatible Regular Expression.

Comment: @Hiten Glad it helped! If a post answers your question, mark it as accepted, so others will know the problem was solved. To do so, check the tick mark, right below the voting arrows.

Comment: Useless use of zcat, do you know zgrep ?

Comment: @sputnick I didn't for the time I answered the OP's question (:

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
zgrep -c '2013-11-21;0[89]:.*abc' file.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Or awk (gawk in linux) will work:

```
zcat *.gz  | awk -F'[\.;:]' '{arr[$2]++} END{for(i in arr){print i, arr[i]} }' 2>/dev/null
```

the redirection is there because some awks, notably gawk, will complain about . not being a metacharacter